# Crystal Report Service Packs Release Notes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I wonder where could I find release notes for Latest Crystal Report SP like 13.0.1, 13.0.2 and 13.0.3
I want to know what are the fixed bugs and new features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this site: http://www.crystaladvice.com/crystalreports/crystal-reports-2010-sp3 It seems to be relatively up-to-date.

SAP/BusinessObjects has some major documentation problems... trying to find what you're looking for at their support site is like diving into a swimming pool full of dilapidated manuals and scribbled bar napkins.